# Race to the Past: A Historical Scavenger Hunt

Tags: visual, cryptic-clues, anagram, crosswords, history

This was intended to be for [History Fortnight](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5275/fortnightly-topic-challenge-14-history), but I didn't quite get it finished up in time.  (I now have [a history](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/33501/breaking-up-is-fun-to-do#comment100715_33501) of just missing these cutoffs.)  Here's the puzzle, though you'll definitely need the bigger version to have a go at it.

[image]

## Notes

- The final answer is a person who would've been quite good at History Fortnight.
- I'm American, so dates are MM/DD/YYYY.
- There are cryptic clues (in crpytic-crossword style) but also non-cryptic clues.  All cryptic clues are followed by **(n)** for clarity, even when there are already boxes for their solutions.
- A complete answer will have all boxes filled in and the correct final answer identified.  (And any additional notes are welcome!)
- The colors do help keep track of which answers go where, but shouldn't be necessary for those color-blind folks out there.
- There's no easy way to make a text version of this, so it's tagged [visual](/questions/tagged/visual).
- The flow of information is not meant to be difficult to follow.  Let me know if you're not sure about something, but a careful look should give you the gist of it.

Comment: Looks awesome!  Wish I had more time right now to give it a good go.  If it's not solved by tomorrow, maybe I'll take a crack at it...

Comment: Can't quite tell what's going on on the right side - is the "or" crossword the "source" of the other four entries?

Comment: @Deusovi Yep, the output from the "or" crossword gets used in a bunch of places.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain I'm starting a CW answer for this one - it might just be too massive for any one person to handle.

Comment: @Rand: I think I've almost got it.

Comment: Re: having "a history of just missing these cutoffs", at least you get them out. :) At this stage, I think I've got more work in progress drafts than I do actually released puzzles (including several from fortnightly challenges).

Comment: How did you create this beautiful poster?

Comment: @Alconja I actually posted this a day later than I would've otherwise, since I'd recently [read your answer here](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41646/whats-a-good-way-to-introduce-someone-to-puzzle-making/41677#41677) and I was polishing!

Comment: @Matsmath First of all, thanks! Second, Adobe Illustrator.  Not too tough once you know some basics, but it did take time.

Comment: @DanRussell - Good man! It shows. :) A great (and well-polished) puzzle, deserving of many more views/votes. (and you've directly inspired me to finish/[release](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42408/read-learn-live-escape) my belated entry for the mazes fortnightly challenge).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filled out scavenger hunt:

> [image]

Thanks to Deusovi and whoever helped on the comments to that answer!

Comment: Awesome! Nicely done.  The only issue is that Time/Middle in the bottom crossword should really be Face/Circle.  (Even though time/middle perfectly fit the clues...oops.) That way all the pairings will be correct stories.

Comment: Also TREATY instead of PALACE.

Answer (score 4):

I have to take a break for now - I'm *really* close, though. If anyone wants to finish it off, feel free.

> [image]

Comment: (I *hate* when real life gets in the way of puzzles...)

Comment: 3rd clue in the 2nd crossword should be TREATY (as in Naval Treaty).

Comment: World leader / satellite is BAN KI MOON

Comment: 1st clue in the 2nd crossword should be FACE (as in Yellow Face - I made the same mistake on that one). 1st clue in the 1st crossword is FINAL (as in Final Problem).

Comment: 6th clue in the 1st crossword is NOBLE (as in Noble Bachelor).

Comment: Gloop is AUGUSTUS.

Comment: A bit of warmth ...: CLAUDIUS (a more than averagely involved clue).

Comment: I don't believe it's ALL SAINTS _____; why would those Roman emperors yield SAINTS? Perhaps ALL ROMANS ORDERED, but I hope there's something more specific and enlightening.

Comment: Star / tail is GATE and free / time is TRIAL, which yields Watergate Seven Trial in 1974.

Comment: Hm, so now all that's left is "snot scan" and "faster to take".

Comment: "Equator approximately" must be Circle

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan The "Claudius" clue was the one I was most proud/tickled about writing.  Not sure if it's strictly perfect, but I was pleased with it!

Comment: I had fun solving that one.