# Read. Learn. Live. Escape

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, letter-sequence, anagram, poetry, mazes

You wake lying face down on a hard stone floor. Your head hurts. As your eyes find focus, you see a haiku scratched into the ground beside you:

<kbd>A wrong step brings death!

But, a wrong guess brings knowledge…

Read. Learn. Live. Escape.</kbd>

Death? Escape? You leap up and scan your surroundings... You're in a large smooth-walled cavern, whose floor is made entirely of a grid of seemingly floating stone platforms, suspended somehow over an immeasurable drop. The only way out appears to be a doorway on the far side of the room. As you stare, you notice that each platform has a single letter carved into it. You quickly note them down:

$$
\begin{matrix}
\fbox{R} & \fbox{U} & \fbox{Y} & \fbox{E} & \fbox{R} & \fbox{O} & \color{blue}{\fbox{▲}} & \fbox{L} & \fbox{N} & \fbox{R} & \fbox{A} & \fbox{E} & \fbox{Y} \\
\fbox{A} & \fbox{R} & \fbox{D} & \fbox{Y} & \fbox{E} & \fbox{E} & \fbox{R} & \fbox{U} & \fbox{O} & \fbox{F} & \fbox{M} & \fbox{O} & \fbox{T} \\
\fbox{C} & \fbox{U} & \fbox{L} & \fbox{A} & \fbox{A} & \fbox{T} & \fbox{Y} & \fbox{L} & \, & \fbox{S} & \fbox{A} & \fbox{I} & \, & \\
\fbox{B} & \fbox{T} & \fbox{W} & \fbox{O} & \fbox{T} & \fbox{H} & \fbox{E} & \fbox{N} & \fbox{D} & \fbox{I} & \fbox{I} & \fbox{W} & \fbox{N} \\
\fbox{E} & \fbox{E} & \fbox{D} & \fbox{E} & \fbox{O} & \fbox{R} & \fbox{M} & \fbox{F} & \fbox{D} & \fbox{A} & \fbox{D} & \fbox{N} & \fbox{E} \\
\fbox{N} & \fbox{L} & \fbox{N} & \fbox{I} & \fbox{R} & \fbox{S} & \fbox{R} & \fbox{A} & \fbox{E} & \fbox{N} & \fbox{M} & \fbox{I} & \, \\
\fbox{O} & \fbox{A} & \fbox{E} & \fbox{R} & \fbox{O} & \fbox{M} & \fbox{T} & \fbox{B} & \fbox{U} & \fbox{A} & \fbox{R} & \fbox{O} & \fbox{T} \\
\fbox{K} & \fbox{A} & \fbox{E} & \fbox{T} & \, & \fbox{E} & \fbox{C} & \fbox{N} & \fbox{O} & \fbox{D} & \fbox{A} & \fbox{E} & \fbox{R} \\
\fbox{A} & \, & \fbox{E} & \fbox{A} & \fbox{P} & \fbox{T} & \fbox{H} & \fbox{A} & \fbox{N} & \, & \fbox{T} & \fbox{O} & \fbox{P} \\
\fbox{T} & \fbox{A} & \fbox{F} & \fbox{S} & \fbox{Y} & \fbox{E} & \, & \fbox{O} & \fbox{S} & \fbox{A} & \fbox{G} & \fbox{I} & \fbox{O} \\
\fbox{O} & \fbox{H} & \fbox{E} & \fbox{P} & \fbox{R} & \fbox{F} & \fbox{R} & \fbox{O} & \fbox{M} & \fbox{T} & \fbox{H} & \fbox{E} & \fbox{T} \\
\fbox{U} & \fbox{Y} & \fbox{O} & \fbox{N} & \fbox{O} & \fbox{W} & \fbox{E} & \fbox{S} & \fbox{E} & \fbox{A} & \fbox{M} & \fbox{T} & \fbox{I} \\
\fbox{D} & \fbox{N} & \fbox{A} & \color{green}{\fbox{▲}} & \fbox{C} & \fbox{S} & \fbox{P} & \fbox{E} & \fbox{A} & \fbox{E} & \fbox{S} & \fbox{O} & \fbox{G} \\
\end{matrix}
$$

You're standing on the platform represented by the green arrow ($\color{green}{▲}$) in the bottom row. To reach the door, and thus freedom, you need to cross the room to the platform on the far side indicated by the blue arrow ($\color{blue}{▲}$). You take a breath to calm yourself and make the following observations:

- The platforms are large, but if necessary, you estimate that **you could safely jump completely over one to another**, as well as **jump diagonally** between them, though not completely over one on the diagonal (I.e. from $\color{green}{▲}$, you could safely reach any of the nearby $\text{N}$, $\text{A}$, $\text{C}$, $\text{S}$, $\text{O}$, $\text{N}$, $\text{O}$, and $\text{P}$ platforms - *[see addendum at the bottom of this post for an example]*)
- The platforms are too spaced out to spread your weight between more than one at a time, so when jumping you're going to have to commit yourself fully and assume, based on the haiku, that **leaping to any invalid platform, will result in it collapsing, leading to death**
- There are some missing platforms in the grid, which can obviously be jumped over if necessary, but are otherwise impassible

### What platforms can you safely traverse in order to escape?

*You're only going to get one shot at this, so you better be damn sure of your path before you take that first leap...*

---

<sub>For convenience, here's an ascii/csv version of the floor tiles, since MathJax seems to render matrices in columns:</sub>

```
R,U,Y,E,R,O,▲,L,N,R,A,E,Y,
A,R,D,Y,E,E,R,U,O,F,M,O,T,
C,U,L,A,A,T,Y,L, ,S,A,I, ,
B,T,W,O,T,H,E,N,D,I,I,W,N,
E,E,D,E,O,R,M,F,D,A,D,N,E,
N,L,N,I,R,S,R,A,E,N,M,I, ,
O,A,E,R,O,M,T,B,U,A,R,O,T,
K,A,E,T, ,E,C,N,O,D,A,E,R,
A, ,E,A,P,T,H,A,N, ,T,O,P,
T,A,F,S,Y,E, ,O,S,A,G,I,O,
O,H,E,P,R,F,R,O,M,T,H,E,T,
U,Y,O,N,O,W,E,S,E,A,M,T,I,
D,N,A,▲,C,S,P,E,A,E,S,O,G,
```

---

**Edit**: To be 100% clear about "legal" moves (i.e. jumps that you're physically capable of making), here's a diagrammatic version of the explanation:

$$
\begin{matrix}
\color{red}{\fbox{A}} & \color{red}{\fbox{B}} & \color{blue}{\fbox{C}} & \color{red}{\fbox{D}} & \color{red}{\fbox{E}} \\
\color{red}{\fbox{F}} & \color{blue}{\fbox{G}} & \color{blue}{\fbox{H}} & \color{blue}{\fbox{I}} & \color{red}{\fbox{J}} \\
\color{blue}{\fbox{K}} & \color{blue}{\fbox{L}} & \color{green}{\fbox{●}} & \color{blue}{\fbox{M}} & \color{blue}{\fbox{N}} \\
\color{red}{\fbox{O}} & \color{blue}{\fbox{P}} & \color{blue}{\fbox{Q}} & \color{blue}{\fbox{R}} & \color{red}{\fbox{S}} \\
\color{red}{\fbox{T}} & \color{red}{\fbox{U}} & \color{blue}{\fbox{V}} & \color{red}{\fbox{W}} & \color{red}{\fbox{X}} \\
\end{matrix}
$$

So if you were standing on the green dot ($\color{green}{●}$) in the centre, you would be able to safely jump to any of the blue letters ($\text{C}$, $\text{G}$, $\text{H}$, $\text{I}$, $\text{K}$, $\text{L}$, $\text{M}$, $\text{N}$, $\text{P}$, $\text{Q}$, $\text{R}$ and $\text{V}$). If any of those platforms were missing, you obviously couldn't land there, however, if $\text{H}$, $\text{L}$, $\text{M}$, or $\text{Q}$ were missing, you could still reach $\text{C}$, $\text{K}$, $\text{N}$, or $\text{V}$.

Comment: This was originally intended for the ['mazes' fortnightly challenge](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/5084/5208), but I missed the cut-off so didn't end up finishing it. However, [Dan Russell inspired me to polish it and actually get it out the door anyway](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/42325/5208).

Comment: How can we "Read. Learn. Li**v**e. Escape" without any **v**?

Comment: @JonathanAllan - Read [the haiku]. Learn [from it]. [Do a few, as yet not explicitly defined, steps here]. Live [long enough to] Escape.

Comment: I can't understand it clearly - is there some clues on the haiku on where to jump, or why I can't jump to next plate randomly ?

Comment: @ArkaKarmakar - you can't jump randomly because you can only physically jump so far, and if you jump to the wrong platform it will collapse and you'll fall to your death. [Think Indiana Jones](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=arMXzgiZsJQ), but with the platforms larger and further apart. As for clues, re-read the haiku...

Comment: @Alconja If I jump randomly in the tiles upto which I can jump, even then I will die ? So haiku must provide some clues on where to jump.

Comment: @ArkaKarmakar - Correct on both counts. As per the last directive: "You're only going to get one shot at this, so you better be damn sure of your path before you take that first leap". The haiku gives the first of several clues, which will collectively give you confidence in a given path.

Comment: @Arka: You can reach any tile within two horizontally or vertically, or one tile diagonally.

Comment: @ArkaKarmakar - What Deusovi said, though I've made an edit so that it's hopefully 100% clear.

Comment: @Alconja You're so mean... Posting this puzzle on a monday morning. How can I work now?

Comment: @IAmInPLS - Bah, this is a quick little one. Consider it a mental warm up to get you in the zone and be more productive for the rest of your day. ;)

Comment: I can read "now from the top read" stating from the N above the green arrow., in this continuous path: 3 on the right, 1 up, 7 right, 3 up, 3 left. But still it does not bring me any knowledge

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### Final answer

Continuing where Rand left off, we

> Read off the letters, moving the value of each letter. So if we hit an A, we go forward 1 to reach the next; if B, we skip one and go to the second, and so on. Starting with the R in the top-left corner and going right (wrapping around back to the left side when we hit the right edge), this gives us:
>  [image]
>  "REMAINDER ARE ANAGRAMS".
>
>  Now if we look at each section delimited by the path, holes, and yellow squares, we can anagram them to get a word. These words form the message:
>  "You're nearly ready to actually win freedom, and nil remains but to take a *path to safety*, so I hope you see it and escape. Go!"
>
>  The phrase "PATH TO SAFETY" spells out a valid way to get to the exit!
>  [image]

Comment: Wow!  Great puzzle alconja!  Nice work Deusovi!  I played with so many variations of the A1 B2... clue and it never occurred to me to do what you did. Hope this gets voted up a ton!

Answer (score 13):

### Partial answer

Treating the puzzle like a wordsearch yielded some interesting results:

> [image: path]

We have a path from the bottom to the top which gives a rhyming couplet:

> Now from the top read once more:
>  A one, B two, then D is four.

<sub>(Thanks to @Wu33o for helping to complete this message.)</sub>

So far there have been no diagonal or two-square jumps; this clearly isn't the final answer to the puzzle. Besides, remember the words of the haiku: "*a wrong guess brings knowledge*" tells us to guess this (wrong) path in order to find a hidden message which will give us the knowledge needed to find the right path.

I'm not sure what to do with this couplet - there are only two B's in the whole square, and neither of them is near the top. It's possible we may be able to get other similar paths and couplets, since I found more words hidden within the square that haven't been used yet - YEAR, NEAR, and most suspiciously MORE THAN:

> [image: more words]

There's also an [anagram](/questions/tagged/anagram) tag, which I haven't yet worked out what to do with. Perhaps the haiku given in the question anagrams to something useful?

Comment: An excellent (though partial) wrong guess to make.

Comment: @Alconja Wrong guess? You mean those words I've found aren't even relevant? :-(

Comment: @randal'thor Well if your guess is wrong it will probably be relevant, according to the haiku

Comment: Ha! No, sorry, very relevant... "wrong guess" as in if you were guessing a path out of the maze, that would be wrong, but as we know "*a wrong guess brings knowledge*".

Comment: @Alconja Aha, good, so I am on the right lines then! You had me worried for a moment there.

Comment: Perhaps the second part of the verse is (Rot13:) _n bar o gjb gura q vf sbhe_, which we can use in another step

Comment: @Wu33o Hmm, possible, but there are other words hidden in there. I've found a "year", a "near", and a "than" as well.

Comment: And you never jumped diagonally *once*?

Comment: @Matsmath Not yet. This is only the first stage.

Comment: The wording of this couplet makes me think it's actually the _second_ part of the puzzle.

Comment: @MariaDeleva Sorry, where are these paths?

Comment: So maybe that last bit could be spelling out a simple cipher?  but to what?

Comment: Interestingly, the 6 letters to the right of the green arrow anagram to "escape"; I wonder if that's relevant?

Comment: I have got ton other words, all separated, YARD END FROM TAKE THAN TOP PEA OTHER YOU SEAM AND PEAS FEAT SATIRE FEET NEEDLE TO TEAR MET THOR. One another wrong knowledgable path of probably from the left of the start, AND TAKE ... or AND OTHER ...

Comment: The five letters to the right of the blue arrow anagrams to "learn"( as given in the haiku)...

Comment: @Sid So thanks to you and Ankoganit, we've found both LEARN and ESCAPE. But it'll be impossible to find LIVE, since there's no V in the whole grid.

Comment: @randal'thor which apparently means it is a wrong step and might lead to death!

Comment: @Sid - Maybe that's why it's just A/One, B/Two, and D/Four, with no C/Three.  Also, READ (un-anagramed) is part of the message we've found, so there's the fourth word.

Comment: @Alconja, you said this is a partial wrong guess.  Are you saying there is more to the wrong guess or that this is only part of the solution?  This puzzle is killing me!

Comment: @Bobson - that there's no c/3 is definitely a clue, but not for that reason...

Comment: @SteveMangiameli - No, when rand originally posted it was only partial. He subsequently edited. It is now the "complete" wrong guess as intended. From the top: A1, B2, D4 is now the clue to be working on...

Comment: OK good.  Well good that we have a verified clue.  Bad that I have yet to crack it.  I tried using them as grid coordinates but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: @Alconja Starting from the top left square, we can jump **one** square down to reach **A**, and then another **two** down to reach **B** ... is this relevant at all?

Comment: @Alconja: OK, how is the absence of C/3 "definitely a clue"?

Comment: @PeregrineRook - Because A1, B2, D4 follows the pattern required for the second step (if you imagine it projected on an alphabet). I.e. if you start on A, you'd jump 1 forward to B, then 2 forward to D, then 4 forward... etc (or at least that was my intention).

Comment: @Alconja: We're not communicating. Yes, I read Deusovi's answer, where he jumps 5 forward from `E`, 7 forward from `G`, 9 forward from `I`, etc. How is A/1 B/2 D/4 a better clue for that than A/1 B/2 C/3 would be?

Comment: @PeregrineRook - A1, B2, C3, D4, E5, etc shows that the letters have "value" but that's fairly obvious and not very useful. Switching it to A1, B2, D4, H8, etc provides additional information about the process applied based on those values. If you had the whole alphabet written out the first way, you'd get nowhere, if you had the full alphabet stepped out the second way, you'd probably get it immediately. The fact that you only got A, B, D makes it much harder, but at least gives you something...

Comment: @PeregrineRook - three doesn't rhyme with "more" but four does.  Either way the clue is conveyed the same.