# Who was the US president in [oh rubbish, I forgot the year]?

Tags: knowledge, crosswords

I've been trying to remember who was the US president in the yea-

Oh...

Oh god, which year was it again?

Anyway, I wrote down a note to myself while I was sleepy last night. If anybody can help me find the answer I'd really appreciate it.

[image]

*Just so I don't forget in future, if somebody could try to give me the answers to all parts of this - I'd really appreciate it...Also, I really need a better way of noting down important information in future.*

Comment: Obvious first-puzzle-I've-ever-made-disclaimer, any feedback would be much appreciated; especially with difficulty/tags and so on. Hope it's a quick fun one to solve.

Comment: This is quite good for a first puzzle! Since you asked for feedback, some things I think would make this better: make it a bit less shortcutable (......s of the old re...blic should be completable by most gamers without doing the earlier steps) and maybe mix in some more creative associations with the trivia. [This puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/42325/20521) is one in the same style I thought was really good.

Comment: I agree with the above, I was also able to solve it instantly from the bottom part, I didn't even look at the top part. Otherwise a very clever puzzle, and a terrific first attempt!

Comment: Minor nitpick: In future puzzles, make sure you don't have that red squiggle from "typos" (unless, obviously, they're part of the puzzle). In Word, you can hide them by right-clicking and finding "ignore this error"; I'm sure there are equivalent options in most software.

Comment: Thanks all! Will take all that on board for the next one

Comment: That was fun, thank you. Agree with the other comments though, I guessed Knights of the old Republic right away so skipped the earlier clues. Good work though. :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It was:

> Obama

The Son of Lancelot is:

> Sir **Galahad**, giving Galahad **Knight**mare Frame [Code Geass]

Carry something heavy is:

> Lug, and a Green Leafy Vegetable is a Lettuce, giving Slug and Lettuce, a *Pub* chain

This gives us:

> Knights of the Old Republic, a video **Game**

So far we have the film as:

> "The ______ Games"

A common programming placeholder is:

> Foo, giving A lack of Food, or **Hunger**

Thus the film is:

> The Hunger Games, making the year 2012, Obama's administration

Comment: Absolutely spot on. Hope it was as fun to solve as it was to make.

Comment: Though not difficult per se, since only the penultimate blanks are needed, it's definitely a fun little Trivia game (Geass I would never have gotten though) :p

Comment: @Bilkokuya: FWIW, assuming you want feedback, I think it was too easy to get the President compared with solving the whole problem properly. I got the placeholder, hence the "lack of", hence the film title, then I knew what President even though I didn't know the exact year. Solving the rest upwards was easier for me than downwards. Which is fine as long as you intended that to be one way of solving the whole thing :-)